# How do i pass a js variable from one html file to another?

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables

My problem is pretty simple, but as i still lack proficiency in merging js,php and html, i couldn't find a solution for this problem.
The problem involves 3 files:

JS1.js

```
function foobar(foo){
...
}
```

**here foo is the same foo generated from HTML1.html file**

HTML1.html

```
...<?php
$something = Object->method();
$array = Object->anotherMethod($something);
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
            var foo =" . json_encode($array) . ";
     </script> ";
?>
...
```

**here i generate the json_encode(d) version of my php array**

HTML2.html

```
...<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/JS1.js">
</head>
<body>
...
... onClick = \"foobar(foo)\">";
...
</body>
```

**here, basically, i need it as the parameter to run my foobar js function in JS1.js file**

So my question is, **how do i pass foo from HTML1.html to HTML2.html**?

*PS: obivously i have 2 splitted html files because i need them both and both do different things otherwise the problem would have never even occurred :) just to clear things up*

Comment: How are you making the page change? A standard link, or is it happening in the js function?

Comment: Can't you just generate this var `foo` in the JS file and just include it in both files? Or can't I just get your problem? ..

Comment: Variables don't maintain scope between HTML pages.

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying, i'll try the cookie thing.
To answer your question, Jiving, the page change is done through a form button, because basically HTML1.html shows a list of fields (the array) and HTML2.html, through JS1.js, is supposed to process that list and do something else.

Comment: If it's just a form and you only need the variable once then cookies are overkill. You could use `GET` or `POST` methods on your form to pass the information.

Comment: i also thought about that but wouldn't the parameter be too long to be passed through URL string?
Can you kindly provide me an easy example for the case i wrote down?
Because, yes, as a matter of fact, i need the json string only once in HTML2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case use a cookie :
IN HTML1 , after setting var foo, set it in a cookie
then get it from the HTML2

HELPER CODE (http://www.w3schools.com)
in js :

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

and

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. To make it elegant i could do this:
1)Make a JS2.js file and write down those 2 functions
2)include JS2.js as a script inside both my HTML1.html and HTML2.html files
3)call setCookie (name, foo, 10) in HTML1.html
4)call getCookie (name) in HTML2.html

is that right?

Comment: Jivings was also suggesting that for my specific case, as i need the parameter to be used only once, cookies could be not the best solution. He suggested to use a POST call to send data to the other page, but honestly i don't know how to do it with a json string.

Answer (score 0):

theres 2 ways you could do it,

- 1: [easyest,cleanest] set a cookie on the browser that javascript can
  read. [w3schools.com on javascript cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

or

- 2: [this is a very bad idea] have javascript add a value to the end of all
  links to pass the value